# column "xx_xx" can only be updated to DEFAULT - DJANGO

Tags: django, postgresql

Im trying to update some values (via django) at a table on Postgres that contains a Generated column.

This is the error im getting:
**column "xx_xx" can only be updated to DEFAULT**

[See complete error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62Axm.jpg)

Comment: Please post error messages as formatted text - do not post images. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). While this speaks directly about code it still applies to error messages. For error messages copy the complete message and enclose within lines containing only ```

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old but somebody may find it later

Even though Generated Columns were introduced in Postgres12 (4 years ago) I couldn't find proper support for it in Django, so I built one myself

This answer is inspired by https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21454

and from Django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-model-fields/

This is a generic field [accepts `base_field` similar to ArrayField]
you can use it as

```py
line_total = GeneratedField(
    base_field=models.IntegerField(),
    expression=F("price") * F("quantity"),
    help_text=_("line total, calculated as = price * quantity"),
)
```

notice that you can't reference fields from other models or use subqueries or  other generated fields in the expression as mentioned in [postgresql docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html)

```py
from django.db.models import Field
from django.db.models.expressions import BaseExpression
from django.db.models.expressions import Combinable
from django.db.models.fields.mixins import CheckFieldDefaultMixin
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs
from psycopg2.extensions import register_adapter


class PostgresDefaultValueType:
    pass


register_adapter(PostgresDefaultValueType, lambda _: AsIs("DEFAULT"))


class GeneratedField(CheckFieldDefaultMixin, Field):
    def __init__(self, base_field, expression: BaseExpression | Combinable, **kwargs):
        self.base_field = base_field
        self.expression = expression
        kwargs["editable"] = False
        kwargs["blank"] = True
        kwargs["default"] = None
        if hasattr(self.base_field, "from_db_value"):
            self.from_db_value = self._from_db_value
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    @property
    def model(self):
        try:
            return self.__dict__["model"]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute 'model'" % self.__class__.__name__)

    @model.setter
    def model(self, model):
        self.__dict__["model"] = model
        self.base_field.model = model

    def set_attributes_from_name(self, name):
        super().set_attributes_from_name(name)
        self.base_field.set_attributes_from_name(name)

    @property
    def description(self):
        return "Generated Field of %s" % self.base_field.description

    def has_default(self):
        return True

    def _from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        if value is None:
            return value
        return self.base_field.from_db_value(value, expression, connection)

    def db_type(self, connection):
        from django.db.models.sql.query import Query

        base_type = self.base_field.db_type(connection)

        query = Query(model=self.model, alias_cols=False)
        compiler = query.get_compiler(connection=connection)
        sql, params = self.expression.resolve_expression(query).as_sql(compiler=compiler, connection=connection)
        expr = sql % tuple(connection.schema_editor().quote_value(p) for p in params)
        return f"{base_type} GENERATED ALWAYS AS ({expr}) STORED"

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()

        kwargs.update({"base_field": self.base_field.clone(), "expression": self.expression})
        return name, path, args, kwargs

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault("form_class", self.base_field.formfield())
        return super().formfield(**kwargs)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        # inspired by https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21454
        if value is None:  # avoid adding DEFAULT to the query when migrating
            return super().get_prep_value(value)
        return PostgresDefaultValueType()
```

Disclaimer: as mentioned in your question, this answer is only applicable to Postgresql, I guess a slight modification will make it work for MySQL

please mark this as an Accepted Answer if you find it useful

Answer (score 1):

You cannot edit generated column in a way other columns are saved/updated

As  PostgreSQL [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html) states

> A generated column cannot be written to directly. In INSERT or UPDATE commands, a value cannot be specified for a generated column,
> but the keyword DEFAULT may be specified.

Comment: I am trying to use django ORM, but using the vector="DEFAULT" getting the same error.

Comment: And what should I do when I just want to add a record, do not want default value,?